# How to output fewer .ts files with HLS muxer?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any command so that ffmpeg does not generate so many output files when I order to convert to m3u8 (.ts)?

I'm using:

```
-codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_key_info_file E:\convertido\video.key.info
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-hls_time`. This option sets the segment length. Default value is 2 seconds.

See the [FFmpeg HLS muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) for more details.